# Azure Key Vault ClientSecret Management

Tags: c#, console-application, azure-keyvault, app-secret

For me, I have distributable console app to users. Instead of hard-coding the connection strings in the application, I moved those to Key Vault and created the ClientCredentials.

Interactive-user-login or certificate in AAD are not in my options as I do not have admin privileges to consent the API permissions at this moment.

Question, might look like duplicate, where do I keep the key (ClientCreds) to the lock (KeyVault)? Obviously lock 'n' key in place does not do any good.

Note that, even if I hardcode in the console app, it can be reversed by any decompiler. Please assist here.

Answer (score 1):

You've asked the impossible question, but I believe you've made a mistake. AKV access policies require a token but do not need consent to APIs. You can do interactive login without API consent to get an access token for Key Vault.

Comment: In AAD, I registered my application and added API permissions called 'AzKeyVault.user_impersonation'. Added the RegisteredAadClient into access polices of KV. While I try authorize the KeyVaultResourceUri by user creds interactively, it fails by 'AdminConsentMissing' error in AAD.